# How to assign function argument to variable name

Tags: r, function, variables, tidyverse, variable-assignment

Say I have these data:

```
data <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3))
```

And a simple function that creates a data frame. It also creates a new variable based on a simple function; this new variable takes the name that is passed in with `varname`. Here is my attempt (the `assign` line is wrong):

```
fun <- function(varname) {
    data <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3))
    assign(paste0("data$", varname), sqrt(data$a))  
    data
}

fun("newvar")
```

Base R or tidyverse solutions are both great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close! There are multiple ways of subsetting dataframes, including using the `[[.]]` notation (e.g., `data[["var"]]`. Simply assigning a value to a new column initializes the column.

```
fun <- function(varname) {
    data <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3))
    data[[varname]] <- sqrt(data$a)
    data
}

fun("newvar")
```

Answer (score 1):

**tidyverse**

If you want to pass the variable name as a string then a `tidyverse` method would be:

```
library(dplyr)

fun <- function(varname) {
  data.frame(a = c(1,2,3)) %>% 
    mutate(!! varname := sqrt(a))
}

fun("newvar")
```

---

Alternatively, you could use tidyeval so you don't have to quote the variable name:

```
library(dplyr)

fun <- function(varname) {
  varname <- rlang::enquo(varname)
  data.frame(a = c(1,2,3)) %>% 
    mutate(!! varname := sqrt(a))
}

fun(newvar)
```

**base R**

If you want to use base R I would recommend the solution posted by @Noah, but another base R option that is fairly obtuse would be:

```
fun <- function(varname) {
  data.frame(a = c(1,2,3)) |>
    within(eval(substitute(x <- sqrt(a), list(x = as.name(varname)))))
}

fun("newvar")
```

Comment: Great. Why the double !!?

Comment: @bill999 What do you mean why the double?

Comment: Sorry, I meant why are there two exclamation points in the ‘tidyverse’ ‘mutate’ line.

Comment: The `!!` and `:=` are the syntax you use to evaluate `varname` before the variable is created. Otherwise, the name of the new variable would be `varname` instead of `newvar`. See the help page for more detail: ``?`!!` ``

Comment: I will look into that. Thanks!